# Pesquisa de email sem dominio

Tags: mysql, query, email

Estou a fazer uma query para receber vários dados da BD, o que engloba introduzir o campo de email, mas não quero ao fazer pesquisas que seja mostrado emails por causa do domínio.

Por exemplo, tenho um email "**qwerty@abcde.com**"

Com a seguinte query:

`SELECT bb.email FROM bd_email bb WHERE bb.email like '%text_in_search%'`

No campo que irá receber do $_GET [PHP], poderei pesquisar por:

```
- "@abcde"
- "@abcde."
- "cde"
- "e.c"
- ".com"
```

Logicamente pretendo remover este tipo de resultados na query para não mostrar dados indevidamente.

- Mas se pesquisar o email completo, ai sim, retorna um resultado.

Sabem como posso formar esta query?

Comment: uai, não seria  ....WHERE bb.email = 'qwerty@abcde.com'

Comment: Leo Caracciolo: Não, pretendo que ao procurar tudo atras do @ retorne dados, por exemplo apenas "uert".

Comment: tendi mas não tendi a pergunta rs

Comment: Penso já ter conseguido.

O que eu pretendo, é não retorne dados iguais depois do arroba (@) na pesquisa.


Se pesquisar "gmail.com" ou "hotmail.com" vai retornar milhares resultados, e é algo que não quero.


Para já, a minha solução passa por isto:


`SELECT bb.email FROM bd_email bb WHERE bb.email like '%text_in_search%' AND SUBSTRING(bb.email, LOCATE('@', bb.email)) not like '%text_to_search%';`

Comment: É, nem sua pergunta nem seus comentários fizeram muito sentido. Tem como colocar um exemplo de como está seu banco de dados, qual será o valor de `text_in_search` e qual deverá ser o resultado?